# JavaScript - retain "textbox2" value for it to be available after refresh/reopen page

Tags: javascript

I have 2 textboxes. After writing something in the first one and clicking the OK button the value appears in textbox2 also.
I need that value to be saved after page refresh and not be modified untill someone introduces a new value in textbox1 and hits OK again.

```
<html> 
<head> </head> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction() 
    { 
     var first = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;

     var textbox2 = document.getElementById("textbox2");
     textbox2.value = first;

    } 
</script>

 <body> 
<input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1" />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button1" onclick="myfunction()" value="OK" />
<br/>
Your answer is:
<input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" readonly="true"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you can make the "Textbox2" a server control by declaring runat="server" which would retain the value even after server hit as shown below.

```
<input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" readonly="true" runat="server" />
```

Then store it in session (in case of C#) or something similar in the server side to restore the value.

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it every time.  http://jsfiddle.net/CKLAg/

first, simplify your html a bit:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1">
<button name="button" id="button1" onclick="myFunction();">OK</button>
<br/>Your answer is:
<input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" readonly="true">
```

Then, add the following functions to check for localStorage, save and load storage on demand:
Note, that you will have to use jQuery to get the document ready state and set the input element when the DOM is ready.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var prevAnswer = loadStorage;    
    $('#textbox2').attr('value', prevAnswer);
});

function loadStorage() {    
    if (supports_html5_storage) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('myAnswer')) {
            var answer = localStorage.getItem('myAnswer');
            return answer;
        }
    }

}

function myFunction() {
    var first = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
    var textbox2 = document.getElementById("textbox2");

    textbox2.value = first;
    if (supports_html5_storage) {
        alert('storing');
        localStorage['myAnswer'] = first;
    }

}

function supports_html5_storage() {
    try {
        return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```